# ContinuousCalendar - How to set selected date?

Tags: jquery

Anyone familiar with [Continuous Calendar](http://reaktor.github.com/jquery-continuous-calendar/index.html)? This powerful calendar lacks sample codes.

How do you select a date range programmatically?

[The example](http://reaktor.github.com/jquery-continuous-calendar/site/playground.html) shows it can be done. I have gone through the source code but couldn't figure out how they did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it (replace the dates with yours'

`$('#myContainer').append('<input type="hidden" class="startDate" value="' + '05/22/2012' + '" /><input type="hidden" class="endDate" value="' + '05/25/2012' + '"/>')`

or to do it onClick:

```
$('#create').click(function(){
        $('#myContainer').append('<input type="hidden" class="startDate" value="' + $('#selectionStart').val() + '" /><input type="hidden" class="endDate" value="' + $('#selectionEnd').val() + '"/>')

        $('#myContainer').continuousCalendar();
});
```

Here is the running code: [ContinuousCalendar on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaiser110/5ncmL/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put the value to the hidden fields, and make sure the parameter selectToday is false (the default is false)

```
<div id="dateRange1">
  <input type="hidden" class="startDate" name="range_start" value='1/1/2012' />
  <input type="hidden" class="endDate" name="range_end" value='1/2/2012' />
</div>
```